# Identify how many times in a month a report gets access

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL Server v17.4 and am not sure how to create a query that sum's the number of times a user opens a report.

These are the columns:

```
ID (GUID) 
User (Varchar(100) - name to the person who accessed the report
PageName(varchar(200) - report name
DateAccessed (datetime) - date user accessed the report
```

This is my current query but it is not returning what I want:

```
SELECT
    PageName Report,
    [user] UserName,
    FORMAT([DateAccessed],'MMM') Month,
    COUNT(user) Count
FROM 
    DB.Table
GROUP BY 
    PageName, [user], [dateaccessed]
ORDER BY 
    report
```

This is the result I am looking for:

```
Report      User    Month   Accesed
Report#1    Andy    Nov     10
Report#2    Angela  Dec     5
Report#3    Angus   Jan     15
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to fix the `group by`:

```
SELECT PageName as Report, [user] as UserName, FORMAT([DateAccessed], 'MMM') as Month,
       COUNT(*) as Count
FROM DB.Table
GROUP BY PageName, [user], FORMAT([DateAccessed],'MMM')
ORDER BY report, MIN(DateAccessed);
```

You have grouped by the date rather than the month.  This just repeats the expression for the month.

You should ether be explicitly limiting the time from to no more than a year or including the year in the `SELECT`/`GROUP BY` (unless you intentionally want to combine data from different years but the same month).

I also added a second sort key so the months will be in chronological order.